# Spring-Integration-DSL: Nested Scatter Gather hangs

Tags: spring-integration-dsl

Here is a broken, but executable example code:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow testFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Http.inboundChannelAdapter("test")
                    .requestMapping(mapping -> mapping.methods(HttpMethod.GET))
                    .get())
            .scatterGather(
                    scatterer -> scatterer
                            .applySequence(true)
                            .recipientFlow(flow -> flow
                                    .scatterGather(
                                            scatterer1 -> scatterer1
                                                    .applySequence(true)
                                                    .recipientFlow(IntegrationFlowDefinition::bridge),
                                            gatherer -> gatherer.outputProcessor(MessageGroup::getOne))
                                    .log(INFO, m -> "THIS HAPPENS")),
                    gatherer -> gatherer.outputProcessor(MessageGroup::getOne))
            .log(INFO, m -> "THIS NEVER HAPPENS")
            .get();
}
```

The expected output is:

```
THIS HAPPENS
THIS NEVER HAPPENS
```

The actual output is:

```
THIS HAPPENS
```

I found [this identical looking issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3152) on Github, but it claims it has been fixed with versions `5.1.10` and `5.2.4`. I am running spring-boot-starter-integration `5.5.0` which includes spring-integration-core of the same version.

What can I do to get this nested scatter gather to work ? Is it a bug with the DSL or with my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having a similar problem using only one level of scatter-gather, I realized it was the log message that was blocking the output from being returned to the parent flow. Replace `.log()` with `.logAndReply()` or `.log().bridge()` and everything should work again.

Like this:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow testFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Http.inboundChannelAdapter("test")
                    .requestMapping(mapping -> mapping.methods(HttpMethod.GET))
                    .get())
            .scatterGather(
                    scatterer -> scatterer
                            .applySequence(true)
                            .recipientFlow(flow -> flow
                                    .scatterGather(
                                            scatterer1 -> scatterer1
                                                    .applySequence(true)
                                                    .recipientFlow(IntegrationFlowDefinition::bridge),
                                            gatherer -> gatherer.outputProcessor(MessageGroup::getOne))
                                    .logAndReply(INFO, m -> "THIS HAPPENS")), // this fixes the problem
                    gatherer -> gatherer.outputProcessor(MessageGroup::getOne))
            .log(INFO, m -> "THIS NEVER HAPPENS")
            .get();
}
```

Comment: Also, Artem commented on this issue here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues/169

Comment: Please, consider to ask Spring Integration question in `spring-integration` official tag . We don’t monitor this redundant just for DSL. The point is that Java DSL (and Kotlin one) is just a part of main project .